# Is it possible to implement INotifyPropertyChanged as a Type Extension in F#

Tags: mvvm, f#, extension-methods, inotifypropertychanged

In C# you can implement an extension method based on the PropertyChangedEventHandler as follows:

```
  static class VMExts
  {
    public static void RaisePropertyChanged(this PropertyChangedEventHandler handler, object sender, string propName)
    {
      if(handler != null)
      {
        handler(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
      }
    }
  }
```

Which can be called as follows:

```
  class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private string _someText;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string SomeText
    {
      get { return _someText; }
      set
      {
        _someText = value;
        PropertyChanged.RaisePropertyChanged(this, "SomeText");
      }
    }
  }
```

I've been trying to achieve something similar in F# but can't figure out the syntax.
It's obviously pretty easy to achieve this by inheriting from some ViewModelBase style class such as http://www.fssnip.net/2x but it'd be really nice to have an extension method.

So, given this class:

```ml
  type ViewModelBase() =
    let mutable _someText = ""
    let propertyChanged = Event<_, _>()

    interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
      [<CLIEvent>]
      member x.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish

    member x.SomeText 
      with get() = _someText
      and set(value) = 
        _someText <- value
        (x :> INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged.RaisePropertyChanged("SomeText")
```

I've tried:

```ml
  type PropertyChangedEventHandler with
    member x.RaisePropertyChanged(sender, propName) =
      if x <> null then
        x.Invoke(sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName))
```

and

```ml
  open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

  [<Extension>]
  type VmExtensions() =
    [<Extension>]  
    static member inline RaisePropertyChanged(handler : PropertyChangedEventHandler, propName) =
      if handler <> null then
        handler.Invoke(handler, PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName))
```

I think these fail to be found as a valid for the PropertyChanged because the type of PropertyChanged is IEvent whereas I've extended the type PropertyChangedEventHandler.

I therefore then tried:

```ml
  type IEvent<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs> with
    member x.RaisePropertyChanged(sender, propName) =
      if x <> null then
        x.Invoke(sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName))
```

But the compiler doesn't like the usage of the IEvent

```ml
  [<Extension>]
  type VmExtensions() =
    [<Extension>]  
    static member inline RaisePropertyChanged(handler : IEvent<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>, propName) =
//      if handler <> null then
        handler.Invoke(handler, PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName))
```

But IEvent only really has a Subscribe method

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can raise the event via the `Trigger` method, which is defined on `Event` (not on `IEvent`):

```
[<Extension>]
type VmExtensions =
    [<Extension>]  
    static member inline RaisePropertyChanged
        (ev:Event<PropertyChangedEventHandler, _>, propName) =

        ev.Trigger(null, PropertyChangedEventArgs propName)
```

Comment: Ah yeah, that works thanks.  It's a shame that I'll need to cast the IEvent<PropertyChangedEventHandler, _> that is created in the PropertyChanged.Publish.  I'd either need to do that in the RaisePropertyChanged function and raise an exception if the cast fails, or, do it everywhere I am using INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Glad you have found something that works. Could you please check the answer then. On a side note, I don't really understand why you are using an approach who requires casting from `IEvent< , >` to `Event< , >` in the first place. The usual solution to avoid repetitive implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` is to simply inherit from a `ViewModelBase` class (like yours), which has some kind of (internal) `OnNotivyPropertyChanged` method defined who can be called by inheritors. It's not "idiomatic-functional" F#, but it's completely O.K. from a pragmatic point of view.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I forgot that I had already created the Event<> and had access to it so my point about casting was irrelevant.  Using this I have come up with something I quite like as an implementation.